# creating function using newID()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I keep getting this error: Any Ideas?

> Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'newid' within a function.

I am working with `MS-SQL Server 2005`. Here is the `T-SQL` statement:

```
Create Function [dbo].[GetNewNumber](  )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

  Declare @code int

  set @code = (SELECT CAST(CAST(newid() AS binary(3)) AS int) )

  RETURN (@code)
END
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function will not let you use the NewID, but this can be worked around.

```
Create View vwGetNewNumber
as
Select Cast(Cast(newid() AS binary(3)) AS int) as NextID

Create Function [dbo].[GetNewNumber] ( ) RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN
Declare @code int
Select top 1  @code=NextID from vwGetNewNumber
RETURN (@code) 
END
```

Then you can use `select dbo.[GetNewNumber]()` as planned.

Comment: Should i worry about the same number being generated twice or are those chances astronomical???

Comment: They are not beyonds the realms of possibility at all, only a max of 100million numbers available, done by purely random chance. By the birthday problem theory your chances of a match will come sooner than you expect.

Comment: +1, good workaround. Though it may be defensive coding, the `top 1` seems unnecessary in this case and is very slightly slower than without.

Answer (score 11):

You can't use NEWID() within a function.

A usual workaround (in my experience, it's more been the need for GETDATE()) is to have to pass it in:

```
Create Function [dbo].[GetNewNumber](@newid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

  Declare @code int

  set @code = (SELECT CAST(CAST(@newid AS binary(3)) AS int) )

  RETURN (@code)
END
```

And call it like:

```
SELECT dbo.GetNewNumber(NEWID())
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this have to be done with a function call? Whenever I needs this functionality, I just use:

```
checksum(newid())
```

This will generate negative numbers -- if they must be positive, you could use

```
abs(checksum(newid()))
```