# Use a locking hint or top clause for a view which only selects newid()?

Tags: sql-server, view, locking, guid, user-defined-functions

In order to use `newid()` in a UDF, I've created a view that can help me:

```
create view RandomUUID as select newid() as UUID
```

In this way, UDFs can now get access to newid(). [Cool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186692/creating-function-using-newid).

My question, however, is what is the best way to select this?  Does it make sense to add a `TOP 1` or `(nolock)` to the query in my UDF?  As in:

```
select UUID from RandomUUID
```

vs.

```
select top 1 UUID from RandomUUID (nolock) -- Or any other combo of query modifiers
```

UPDATE:

This [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0452/1) demonstrates how this is being used.

Comment: I think adding `nolock` without understanding what it does is careless engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to add (nolock) because there is no record involved to lock!  For the record, `(NOLOCK)` should be written as `WITH (nolock)` from SQL Server 2008 onwards (or was it 2005).

`TOP (1)` will add a SORT operator here that will be extraneous, since there is only ever one row created.

---

You can create it like this:

```
create view RandomUUID as select newid() as UUID;
GO

create function give_me_a_new_id ()
returns uniqueidentifier as
begin
return (select UUID from RandomUUID);
end;
GO
```

Note: `(nolock)` will be optimized away, but `TOP(1)` adds a SORT operation as seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4a39/3/1) (expand the Execution plans).

Comment: I don't know, it seems to follow to me, same reason you make a view for a function call.

Comment: Thanks for the snark. Here's the [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7bfc/4) demoing the usage of this.

Comment: Okay, you still don't need nolock and top(1).

Comment: Good point on the plan comparison. I had noticed that too, but couldn't get any consistently reproducible performance difference even at a million iterations. I was just curious if there were any positive side-effects of modifying the query beyond its most basic form. Thank you for confirming that there aren't.